# When will 'docker build' rebuild a layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I used following command to clone a repo in order to use it in my docker container:

`RUN git clone ssh://my.repo.com/repo`

The problem is, that when building the docker container, docker does not clone the repo again, but used the cached one.

I quick-fixed it by using `docker build --no-cache`, but that rebuilds all the layers.

How can I rebuild a selected layer only?

Comment: I don't know if there is a 'best' workaround but here is your issue explained, some workaround proposed: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1996

Answer (score 3):

In the Dockerfile:

```
ARG CACHEBUST=1
RUN git clone https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git
```

On the command line:

```
docker build -t your-image --build-arg CACHEBUST=$(date +%s)
```

source: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1996#issuecomment-185872769